# Compressing images, which format to choose?

Tags: linux, images, compression

Might be a silly question, but I really don't know much about images formats. I have some family photos in my external hard drive but noticed they are really big and it's taking up space, is there any way I can shrink the file size while maintain "unnoticeable" loss of quality maintaining the same dimension

Using linux, if there's a way to batch it up (recursively) (well, I'm guessing imagemagick?) that'd be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG is the defacto standard for images. It has lossy but variable compression which can go from horrible to absolutely unnoticeable compared to the original.

My recommendation if to use [nconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html) and call it in a loop (foreach for tsch).
The nconvert tool is very powerfull and has a simple syntax. To simply convert and
out the results:

**nconvert -q  -out jpeg -o**

Replace  with a number. 100 gives high the highest and so the least compression.
I find 90 is still excellent quality. **85 is where I find it reasonable.** Try a few settings
on a single file to see which quality is good enough for you.

You can make your files smaller also by dropping non-image data. Add the **-rmeta** flag
for example before the input file name. The **-rexifthumb** flag removes the EXIF thumbnail.
If you do not want to remove all meta data then the **-clean** flag can be used. You have
to pass it a number to tell it what to clean. Use **nconvert -help** for the details.

Comment: Well when I saw I big file 7.5mb to go to 796kb without removing meta or removing thumb or clean, will try later it made me go "wow..." thanks!